# Regular grammar with parity

Tags: regular-language, context-free-grammar, parity

Give a regular grammar that generates the set of strings over {a, b, c} with an odd number of occurrences of the substring bc.

How can you limit the number of recursions for a regular grammar to be a specific parity?

So I came up with this.

S > bA | aS | Sc | bS  
A > cB  
B > bC | bB | aB  
C > cD  
D > bE  
E > cB | Ea | cE | terminate

Comment: OK, I updated my answer to match what you wrote.

Comment: Your grammar is not regular.

Comment: Are you referring to the answer I posted or the syntax with which I wrote it?

Comment: You have for instance the rules $S \to aS$ and $S \to Sc$, so your grammar is linear, but it is neither left linear nor right linear and hence it is not regular.

Comment: So I can only add a terminal on either the left or right side?

Comment: Alright, I edited my post to give you the full answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An odd parity means at least one bc will occur.  So start with that.

Then, you need to surround it on the left and right with the different possible combinations that can occur.

That is the right idea.  However, it does not provide for a way to terminate with just the string "bc".

Also, the following is possible with the machine you wrote:

S -> bA -> bcB -> bcbC -> bcbcD -> bcbcbE -> terminate.

In this case, there is an even under of bc's.

Should I give you the answer, or would you like another try?

Edit 2: Alright, here is the answer:

```
 S -> aS | cS | bT //even number of bc's has been encountered
 T -> aS | bT | cA //even number of bc's, and then b some time after
 A -> aA | bB | cA | END //odd number of bc's has been encountered
 B -> aA | bB | cS | END //odd number of bc's, and then b some time after
```

This is as simple as it gets, and very intuitive.

---

EDIT: The below is what we called regular grammar; what is described in the updated post is something we called Finite State Machine.  I will put my answer to that on top, leaving my original answer below.

For example:

$c^*(bcbc)^*$, $b^*(bcbc)^*$

However, since you don't wish for bc to occur together, you do not wish to do $[c^*(bcbc)^* b^*(bcbc)^* a^*(bcbc)^*]^*$.  You will need at least one $a$ after each $b$ and before the next $c$.  So something like: $[c^*(bcbc)^* b^*(bcbc)^*a a^*(bcbc)^*]^*$

Let me know if you need further hints.

Comment: See my original post, formatting for comments is bad.

Comment: Give me a moment to look over it, thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Would migrating the terminate from E to B solve this issue or make more issues arise?

Comment: No, it would make more issues arise.  For example, I think you would need to switch Sc | bS into cS | Sb.  Possibly more issues after that.  Try re-doing it from scratch.

Comment: Alright, I'll have to look at it again after work tomorrow with fresh eyes.  Thanks for your help Alex, I'm pretty confident I can get this solved!

Comment: It's a bit simpler than your try.  Just keep in mind what it has to include, and go from there.
p.s., can I have an upvote for my work today?

Comment: I tried to give one but I think I need 15 reputation or something along those lines to effect the score.

Comment: Just let me know when you've an answer ready, or you want me to give you the correct one.  Also, I believe you can still accept answers even though you don't have 15 reputation.

Comment: The answer I came up with is really excessive.  I'm pretty sure it works but it is really verbose.  Could you give me your solution if you still have it around?